# What is an async chunk in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting

This is probably a dummy question but after reading [split-chunks-plugin documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) and [this article about code splitting](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366), i still can't understand what an `async` chunk refers to.

The [split-chunks-plugin documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) states about the `chunks` property that :

> [it] indicates which chunks will be selected for optimization. If a string is provided, possible values are all, **async**, and initial. Providing all can be particularly powerful because it means that chunks can be shared even between **async** and **non-async chunks**.

What is the difference between an async chunk and a non-async chunk ? Is it linked to [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) ?

For example :

```
if (myCondition) {
    import('myLib').then(myLib => {
        // Do something
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading [Chunk](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/Chunk.js) entity from [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) source code, i found the following piece of code :

```
getAllAsyncChunks() {
    const queue = new Set();
    const chunks = new Set();

    const initialChunks = intersect(
        Array.from(this.groupsIterable, g => new Set(g.chunks))
    );

    for (const chunkGroup of this.groupsIterable) {
        for (const child of chunkGroup.childrenIterable) {
            queue.add(child);
        }
    }

    for (const chunkGroup of queue) {
        for (const chunk of chunkGroup.chunks) {
            if (!initialChunks.has(chunk)) {
                chunks.add(chunk);
            }
        }
        for (const child of chunkGroup.childrenIterable) {
            queue.add(child);
        }
    }

    return chunks;
}
```

What i'm seeing here is that an async Chunk is a chunk that is not present in the chunk groups initially (`if (!initialChunks.has(chunk))`). This let me think that an async chunk is a chunk which is loaded afterwards, for example at runtime.

So if i get it right, the previous example will produce an async chunk :

```
if (myCondition) {
    import('myLib').then(myLib => {
        // Do something
    });
}
```

That might also be the case for hot reloading. Hope someone can confirm that.

EDIT :

As @dawncold mentionned in the comment there is this [nice article](https://itnext.io/react-router-and-webpack-v4-code-splitting-using-splitchunksplugin-f0a48f110312) which explains what is a chunk in the first place.

Comment: There is a part of "Understanding chunks", which I think it's useful for me, https://itnext.io/react-router-and-webpack-v4-code-splitting-using-splitchunksplugin-f0a48f110312

Comment: Thanks, nice article !